# Plotting wind vectors on an orthographic projection in Cartopy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-xarray, cartopy

I have a GRIB file with ECMWF temperature and wind data on three pressure levels that I would like to plot with Cartopy using an orthographic projection centred at some longitude, latitude.

The attached plot shows the result that I currently obtain. The script works fairly well, but there is some weird side-effect around the poles when using `quiver()`, where the wind vectors appear in a circle form.

[image: Plot showing wind vectors in weird circular shape]

I tried to use the `regrid_shape=20` keyword option. The effect then disappears and I get about the plot that I am looking for. However, this only works when I use `lat_0=90` in `ccrs.Orthographic(lon_0, lat_0)`.

[image: Figure with regrid_shape=20 option]

If lat_0 its smaller than 90, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xarray_read_grib_pl.py", line 74, in <module>
    regrid_shape=20
  File "/Users/assink/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 310, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/assink/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 1834, in quiver
    target_extent=target_extent)
  File "/Users/assink/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cartopy/vector_transform.py", line 146, in vector_scalar_to_grid
    return _interpolate_to_grid(nx, ny, x, y, u, v, *scalars, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/assink/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cartopy/vector_transform.py", line 68, in _interpolate_to_grid
    method='linear'),)
  File "/Users/assink/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.py", line 221, in griddata
    rescale=rescale)
  File "interpnd.pyx", line 248, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator.__init__
  File "qhull.pyx", line 1839, in scipy.spatial.qhull.Delaunay.__init__
  File "qhull.pyx", line 357, in scipy.spatial.qhull._Qhull.__init__
scipy.spatial.qhull.QhullError: QH6019 qhull input error (qh_scalelast): can not scale last coordinate to [   0,  inf].  Input is cocircular or cospherical.   Use option 'Qz' to add a point at infinity.

While executing:  | qhull d Qbb Qz Qt Q12 Qc
Options selected for Qhull 2019.1.r 2019/06/21:
  run-id 1029403189  delaunay  Qbbound-last  Qz-infinity-point  Qtriangulate
  Q12-allow-wide  Qcoplanar-keep  _pre-merge  _zero-centrum  Qinterior-keep
  Pgood  _maxoutside  0
```

Below is the full code that I use. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fid = 'haiti_hemi_era5_pl_20100122_00.grib'
ds = []

for shortName in ('z', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'q'):
    ds += [xr.open_dataset(fid,
                           engine='cfgrib',
                           backend_kwargs={'filter_by_keys': {'shortName': shortName}})]
ds = xr.merge(ds, combine_attrs='override')

temp = ds.t - 273.15
temp_lim = {'min': -50.0, 'max': 0.0}

windspeed = np.sqrt(ds.u**2+ds.v**2)
wind_lim = {'min': 20.0, 'max': 100.0}

lon_0 = -35.0
lat_0 =  70.0
n_levels = len(ds.isobaricInhPa.values)

lon_idx = slice(None,None,10)
lat_idx = slice(30,None,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, n_levels,
                       subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.Orthographic(lon_0, lat_0)},
                       figsize=(12,8)
                       )

for ilev in range(0,n_levels):
    level_hpa = ds.isobaricInhPa.values[ilev]
    print('Plotting level: {} hPa'.format(level_hpa))
    im1 = temp.isel(isobaricInhPa=ilev).plot.imshow(
                                        cmap='Spectral_r',
                                        interpolation='bicubic',
                                        ax=ax[0,ilev],
                                        transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                                        vmin=temp_lim['min'],
                                        vmax=temp_lim['max'],
                                        add_colorbar=False
                                        )
    ax[0,ilev].set_title('{} hPa'.format(level_hpa))
    ax[0,ilev].coastlines()

    v_mag = windspeed.isel(isobaricInhPa=ilev)
    im2 = v_mag.plot.imshow(cmap='inferno_r',
                           interpolation='bicubic',
                           ax=ax[1,ilev], 
                           transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                           vmin=wind_lim['min'],
                           vmax=wind_lim['max'],
                           add_colorbar=False
                           )
    
    # superimpose wind direction
    lat_ = ds.u.isel(isobaricInhPa=ilev).latitude.values[lat_idx]
    lon_ = ds.u.isel(isobaricInhPa=ilev).longitude.values[lon_idx]
    u_ = (ds.u.isel(isobaricInhPa=ilev)).where(
        v_mag > wind_lim['min']).values[lat_idx,lon_idx]
    v_ = (ds.v.isel(isobaricInhPa=ilev)).where(
        v_mag > wind_lim['min']).values[lat_idx,lon_idx]
    ax[1,ilev].quiver(lon_, lat_, u_, v_,
                scale=1000,
                headlength=5,
                minlength=2,
                headwidth=3,
                width=0.009,
                transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                edgecolor='w',
                linewidth=0.75,
                regrid_shape=20
                )
    ax[1,ilev].set_title('')
    ax[1,ilev].coastlines()

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2, top=0.8, left=0.1, right=0.9, wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)

cb_ax = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.925, 0.75, 0.02])
cbar = fig.colorbar(im1, cax=cb_ax, orientation='horizontal', extend='both')
cbar.set_label(label='Temperature [deg C]', size=12)

cb_ax = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.1, 0.75, 0.02])
cbar = fig.colorbar(im2, cax=cb_ax, orientation='horizontal', extend='both')
cbar.set_label(label='Wind speed [m/s]', size=12)

plt.savefig('temperature-wind-pl.png')

print(ds)
```